# Unable to update sql table via php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ssms-2017

This is the code I am using to try and update the record.  I do not see any issues but it does not throw an error and states it has run successful.  I have tried a couple of other methods that do the same, it just does not update the row in the MSSQL table.  The database/table is local on my machine running Windows 10 and IIS (I know!!).

```
<?php

/**
 * Use an HTML form to edit an entry in the
 * users table.
 *
 */

 require "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Remediation\config.php";
 require "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Remediation\common.php";

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

   try {
     $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

     $user =[
       "id"        => $_POST['id'],
       "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
       "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],
       "email"     => $_POST['email'],
       "age"       => $_POST['age'],
       "location"  => $_POST['location'],
       "date"      => $_POST['date']
     ];

     $sql = "UPDATE users
             SET id = :id,
               firstname = :firstname,
               lastname = :lastname,
               email = :email,
               age = :age,
               location = :location,
               date = :date
             WHERE id = :id";

   $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute($user);
   } catch(PDOException $error) {
       echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
   }
 }

 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   try {
     $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
     $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
     $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
     $statement->execute();

     $user = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   } catch(PDOException $error) {
       echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
   }
 } else {
     echo "Something went wrong!";
     exit;
 }
 ?>    

 <?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) : ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo escape($_POST['firstname']); ?> successfully 
 updated.</blockquote>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <h2>Edit a user</h2>

 <form method="post">
     <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo 
   escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
     <?php foreach ($user as $key => $value) : ?>
       <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo escape($value); ?>" <?php echo ($key === 'id' ? 'readonly' : null); ?>>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Where exactly am I going wrong.  I can connect, delte and create just fine. Do I need to adjust the $USER or query?

Comment: You shouldn't be updating the `id` if you are using that to find the record. Remove `id = :id,` from your `Update Set` statement and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that query directly in the MSSQL management studio?

After that and you see it's working fine, try to "echo" your POST variables to see if you are getting them correctly.

Comment: Will do, the query works fine in SSMS against the table.

Comment: So don't undestand why it worked in that way, but not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I made a rookie mistake, I was trying to update an ID and timestamp column(s) in MSSQL which is not allowed.  I chANGED MY CODE TO THIS AND IT WORKED FINE:

```
   $user =[
     "id"        => $_POST['id'],
     "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
     "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],
     "email"     => $_POST['email'],
     "age"       => $_POST['age'],
     "location"  => $_POST['location'],
           ];

   $sql = "UPDATE users
           SET firstname = :firstname,
             lastname = :lastname,
             email = :email,
             age = :age,
            location = :location
           WHERE id = :id";
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any `INSERT`. Instead you use only `UPDATE` which means, that an existing record is modified only. Is this that you want?

```
 $sql = "UPDATE users
         SET id = :id,
           firstname = :firstname,
           lastname = :lastname,
           email = :email,
           age = :age,
           location = :location,
           date = :date
         WHERE id = :id";
```

Here you select an (all) records with `id = :id`, and here `SET id = :id` you set `id` to an already set value. Is does'n break something, but it is an hint that something in your logic is wrong.

btw, you allow every client to change the records. Not SQL injection, but most likely very bad.

Comment: Yes, the records are already in the table and are identified via ID. This is just a proof of concept , I will secure after I get working.